# prestashop 1.7 add a field to checkout process (and save it)

Tags: module, task-parallel-library, prestashop

Good day, I've created a module that adds a new field (ask for invoice) during the checkout, I've added it in the payment selection hook.

How I save the field value (it is a checkbox) once the page is submitted? I mean after a payment is been selected and the submit button is pressed?

```
public function hookDisplayPaymentTop()
    {
        /* 
            echo"<pre>";
            print_r($this->context->cart);
            echo"</pre>";
        */

        $sql = 'SELECT vat_number FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'address WHERE `id_address` = '.$this->context->cart->id_address_invoice;
        $vat_number = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);

        if ($vat_number == false) {
            $message = $this->l(' your VAT number is invalid or ');
            $vat_status = 0;
        }else{
            $message = $vat_number;
            $vat_status = 1;
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'usrId' => $this->context->customer->id,
        'vat' => $vat_number,
        'vat_status' => $vat_status,
        'cartId' => $this->context->cart->id
      ]);

      return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/front/doyouinvoice.tpl');
    }
```

and the TPL is like:

```
<h5>Do you need an invoice?</h5>
<div class="ggAskInvoiceError {if $vat_status == 1}hideThisMessage{/if}">
  {l s="You need to add your VAT number in the billing address." m="ggaskinvoice"}
</div>

<div class="ggAskContainer">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="askInvoice" id="askInvoice" {if $vat_status == 0}disabled='disabled'{/if} data-cartid="{$cartId}" > {l s="I need an invoice for this order" m="ggaskinvoice"}</label>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use Tools::isSubmit

I'm not sure if this can work for you,

Try to create a controller in your module like this: in yourModule/controller/controllerName,

```
class yourModuleNameModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        $this>setTemplate('module:yourModuleName//views/templates/front/doyouinvoice.tpl');

        if(Tools::isSubmit('askInvoice')){ //askInvoice is your name button
            //Your php code
        }
    }
}
```

And for the DisplayHook i think you only need to do this

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/front/doyouinvoice.tpl');
```

Comment: $this>setTemplate('module:yourModuleName/views/templates/front/doyouinvoice.tpl');